# How to get data from report in netsuite using webservices request?

Tags: netsuite

I want to get data from  **Reports-->sales-->Sales** by Item Summary in netsuite.Can some one help me how to do this? Which type of record i have to request?

```
  i´m having sales order report contains item,desc,qty and total revenue fields.i need to get these fields values to my application.How to do this integration? Is it possible can we get data from report like standard objects?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the same result using a saved search - create that saved search. Using a webservice call you can use 'Search' object to get the result from that saved search (parameter supplied is the value from saved search in the UI).

Comment: Can you please give me sample code in java...@eliseobeltran

Comment: Check out article id 10801 in Suite Answers for basics and samples for Java code searches. Article 10726 for specifics about accessing saved searches.